# Target specific element with dynamic ID but not others are are similar

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dynamic

I have a group of input boxes that are dynamically built and added to the page. I can control the ID that is placed on the elements but it is wrapped in with a bunch of garbage. For example, I give it an ID of `clientTest` it will render an id of `j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_mod`. There is a total of 7 input boxes that contain this Id but contain different endings. The first part of the ID is also dynamic so I can not hard code anything in.

An example,

```
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkid" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkid" value="000000000000000">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkold" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lkold" value="null">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lktp" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lktp" value="001">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspf" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspf" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspfsub" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest_lspfsub" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest" id="j_id0:j_id2:theForm:clientTest" value="0">
```

I have code that allows me to target specific boxes,

```
var lkid = elementId + "_lkid";
```

The problem is that I do not know how to target the input box that does not have anything tacked on to it. the one that is just `clientTest`. How can I target it without grabbing the others?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question correctly but you could probably do something like `jQuery('[id$="' +id+ '"]')` matching only the ending part of the id attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use this

```
var elem = $('input[name$=clientTest]');
```

The above will just target the element whose `name` attribute ends with `clientTest`

Comment: How can I pass a variable into the name? I try to pass a variable but it just takes the name of the variable instead of what I set the variable to.

Comment: `var name = "clientTest";`
`var elem = $('input[name$='+name+']');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($("input:hidden"), function (index, value) {
    if (value.id.match(/.*:[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
        alert(value.id);
    }
});
```

This will target any `<input type="hidden">` element with an id consisting of only letters (a-Z) after the last ":"

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2yka0ygd/)